# C# & SQL Server query returning null columns on large table

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, .net-core, dapper

I'm running the following query on a table that has about 600 columns:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table 
WHERE [Owner] = 1234
```

I am running this query using EF code-first and Dapper and I'm hitting the same problem with both.

In particular many rows that **DO** have a value are returned as `DBNull` from the query (I verified using SQL Server Management Studio that the columns have data). Curiously enough, it only happens when requesting all the columns (whether using `*` or pulling them explicitly).

For example, if column `Status` has value `"A"`, the query returns `DBNull` as its value. But if instead of the above code (that pulls the 600 columns) I use this query:

```
SELECT [Status] 
FROM Table 
WHERE [Owner] = 1234
```

The `Status` column is correctly populated.

Here is the Dapper code I'm using to process the results:

```
public IList<Dictionary<string, string>> GetData() {
    var sql = "SELECT * FROM Table WHERE [Owner] = 1234";
    var cn = new SqlConnection(serverConnectionString);
    var rows = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();

    using (var reader = cn.ExecuteReader(sql))
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            for (var i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
            {
                var propName = reader.GetName(i).ToLowerInvariant();

                // This is set to DBNull for most, but not all,
                // columns if querying the ~600 columns in the Table
                var propValue = reader.GetValue(i); 

                dict[propName] = propValue?.ToString();
            }

            rows.Add(dict);
        }
    }

    return rows;
}
```

I can't make head or tail of this behavior. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you try running both the queries with some order by clause and see if it gives the same result?

Comment: As an aside, having 600 columns in a table is a *huge* code smell.

Comment: Interesting ! Possibly a bug with dapper ? Do you get the same behaviour when using ADO.Net directly? I will do some tests in our setup as well.

Comment: @Rob I absolutely agree. My team is migrating the data to something much more sanely designed. That's why I need to read all the data from the database.

Comment: @Subbu I've used both Dapper and EF CodeFirst and both give the same result. I have not used ADO.Net directly yet

Comment: Can you try pulling say first 5 or 10 rows just for testing with your first(`select *...`) query? My guess is that 600 Columns + all the data in the table is going beyond memory of SQL server itself and thus returning nothing at all. Can you try pulling out few records from all 600 columns and let us know if that works out or not?

Answer (score 1):

Try Dapper's .Query() extension to return a list of dynamic objects. Below is a quick test:

```
[Test]
public void Test_Large_Number_of_Columns()
{
    const int n = 600;
    var cols = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cols += "col" + i + " varchar(50) null,";
    }

    var create = String.Format("IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.foo', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE dbo.foo; create table foo({0})", cols);

    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Integrated Security=true; Initial Catalog=foo"))
    {
        conn.Execute(create);

        conn.Execute("insert into foo(col300) values('hello') ");

        var result = conn.Query("select * from foo").AsList();

        Assert.That(result[0].col300, Is.EqualTo("hello"));

    }
}
```